# If $f(x) = x^3-3x+1.$, then no. of distinct real roots of $f(f(x)) = 0$

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x) = x^3-3x+1.\;,$ Then no. of  different real solution of the equation $f(f(x)) = 0$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $f(x) = x^3-3x+1\;,$ Then $f'(x) = 3x^2-3 = 3(x-1)(x+1)$

Now for max. and Min., put $f'(x) = 0\;,$ So $x=\pm 1$

Now $f''(x) = 6x\;,$ So at $x=+1\;,$ we get $f''(+1) =6>0\;,$ So $x=1$ is a point of Min.

Now $f''(x) = 6x\;,$ So at $x=-1\;,$ we get $f''(-1) =-6<0\;,$ So $x=-1$ is a point of Max.

So after drawing the graph, we get$f(x)=0$ has $3$ Distinct real roots,

But I did not understand how can i find distinct real roots of $f(f(x)) = 0$

Help me

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f(f(x))=0$ implies that $f(x)=c$ where $c$ is a root of $f$ so that $f(c)=0$.

Since $f(-2)=-1, f(-1)= 3, f(0)=1, f(1)=-1, f(2)=3$ you should be able to locate approximate values for $c$.

Now you need to tell whether the vertical shift in the graph from $f(x)=0$ to $f(x)=c$ changes the number of roots (for each of the values of $c$). If you draw a decently accurate diagram of $f$ over the critical interval, you should be able to do this from the same diagram.

Comment: ya,it is a very good idea. we can quickly find : if $c<-1 or c>3$, then there is only one real root,other wise, there is three roots.( except $c=-1$ or $3$), so there is only one $c<-1$, the other two will fall in (-1,3),the total root will be $3+3+1$

Answer (score 0):

we get $f(f(x))={x}^{9}-9\,{x}^{7}+3\,{x}^{6}+27\,{x}^{5}-18\,{x}^{4}-27\,{x}^{3}+27\,
{x}^{2}-1
$
and your equation has seven real roots 
$-2.091982482, -1.832014327, -1.635435747, -.1792838510, .2211743577, 1.610839970, 1.814719598$
See theorem of Sturm.
The other two roots are imaginary roots.